# using the at sign (@) in database

Tags: php, mysql, symbols

So, I'm making a site (From templates and given links/database) at TAFE, so i can't edit my database. Anywho, when I load my page I get a syntax error about anything near the '@' symbol:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@com.au' at line 1
```

My code is:

```
mysql_select_db($database_sim6a2010, $sim6a2010);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM employeeproject WHERE projectID=" . $_GET['projectID'];
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $sim6a2010) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);

mysql_select_db($database_sim6a2010, $sim6a2010);
$query_Recordset2 = "SELECT * FROM project WHERE projectID=" . $_GET['projectID'];
$Recordset2 = mysql_query($query_Recordset2, $sim6a2010) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2);
$totalRows_Recordset2 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset2);

mysql_select_db($database_sim6a2010, $sim6a2010);
$query_Recordset3 = "SELECT employee.name, employeeproject.hours, employee.imgLocation FROM employee, employeeproject WHERE email=" . $row_Recordset1["email"];
$Recordset3 = mysql_query($query_Recordset3, $sim6a2010) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset3);
$totalRows_Recordset3 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset3);
```

I'm going to point out here, I DO NOT like using mysql, I've been told to on this forum to not use it (And I won't) but this is what we are working with and have to use.
As well as I don't like Dreamweaver's huge "Chuck pointless code on your page", but we are being told we have to use Dreamweaver's recordsets and GUI stuff.

Anywho, so the part that is getting the error is:

```
$query_Recordset3 = "SELECT employee.name, employeeproject.hours, employee.imgLocation FROM employee, employeeproject WHERE email=" . $row_Recordset1["email"];
```

The email part of it, as you would suspect, is filled with stuff like "Sam@com" and stuff, this is causing errors, how do I make PHP know that the @ sybmols in the database aren't bits of code?

Hope I've given enough information. I decided to ask because any searches involving the at sign (@) always come up with using it as code.

Comment: You should use parametrized queries.  This would solve the problem you have here, and it would protect you from SQL injection.  http://bobby-tables.com/php.html has examples.  Also, the `mysql_` functions have been deprecated and should not be used any more.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put string data in single quotes like this:

```
$query_Recordset3 = "SELECT employee.name, employeeproject.hours, employee.imgLocation FROM employee, employeeproject WHERE email='" . $row_Recordset1["email"] . "'";
```

Comment: i tried this just then but got "Column 'email' in where clause is ambiguous" as an error

Comment: @DBeslan Which table are do you want to match `email` against?  Prefix `email` with that table name like `employee.email`.  Also, a bigger problem is that you're selecting from two tables, but you have nothing in the query connecting them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add quotes to `$row_Recordset1["email"]` because it's a string

```
$query_Recordset3 = "SELECT employee.name, employeeproject.hours, employee.imgLocation FROM employee, employeeproject WHERE email='" . $row_Recordset1["email"]."'";
```

**NOTE:**

Don't use mysql_* function. Ther will be deprecated soon. Use PDO or mysqli function.

Also watch out for `SQL Injection` your code look vulnerable.

Comment: i tried this just then but got "Column 'email' in where clause is ambiguous" as an error

Answer (score 0):

Issue #1 addressed by `@G-Nugget` and `@Muthu Kumaran` - Put `email` in single quotes `''`.

```
$query_Recordset3 = "SELECT employee.name, employeeproject.hours, employee.imgLocation FROM employee, employeeproject WHERE email='" . $row_Recordset1["email"] . "'";
```

Issue #2 - "Column 'email' in where clause is ambiguous". You are pulling fields from 2 tables `employee` & `employeeproject`, but do not specify which table for the `email`.

```
$query_Recordset3 = "SELECT employee.name, employeeproject.hours, employee.imgLocation FROM employee, employeeproject WHERE employee.email='" . $row_Recordset1["email"] . "'";
```

Although the better way to do this query is with [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html)

```
$query_Recordset3 = "SELECT employee.name, employeeproject.hours, employee.imgLocation FROM employee LEFT JOIN employeeproject ON employee.name=employeeproject.name  WHERE employee.email='" . $row_Recordset1["email"] . "'";
```